# Customise a Tailwind class

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Is there a way I can achieve this css style in tailwind css?

```
.card{
max-width: 48rem;
width: 100%;
```

}

I have tried "max-w-3xl w-full" and it didn't work

Comment: Could you provide a minimal reproducible demo (preferrably in https://play.tailwindcss.com/) ?

Comment: I've tested `max-w-3xl w-full` and it works

Comment: Shouldn't I be asking you that? https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-kare-7ijmx?file=/index.html

Comment: @MoroOwusuAfriyie you should provide minimal reproducible demo by yourself

Comment: I added a items-center to a flex box div to center it so i guess that's what is causing it not to work. but when i removed it, it worked so i'm now coming to center the div without flex box